# Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 Beta 4) - CCCrypt Cannot Invoke Error

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6.3

Just updated to the latest Xcode 6.3 Beta 4 and I'm getting an error I cannot seem to figure out.

There error is:

Cannot invoke 'CCCrypt' with an argument list of type '(CCOperation, CCAlgorithm, CCOptions, UnsafePointer, (Int), nil, UnsafePointer, UInt, UnsafeMutablePointer, (Int), inout UInt)'

With the following code:

```
let keyBytes         = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(keyData.bytes)
let keyLength        = size_t(kCCKeySizeAES128)

let dataLength    = UInt(self.length)
let dataBytes     = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(self.bytes)

let bufferData:NSMutableData! = NSMutableData(length:Int(dataLength) + kCCBlockSizeAES128)
var bufferPointer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(bufferData.mutableBytes)
let bufferLength  = size_t(bufferData.length)

let operation: CCOperation = UInt32(kCCEncrypt)
let algoritm:  CCAlgorithm = UInt32(kCCAlgorithmAES128)
let options:   CCOptions   = UInt32(kCCOptionECBMode)
var numBytesEncrypted: UInt = 0

var cryptStatus = CCCrypt(operation,
            algoritm,
            options,
            keyBytes,
            keyLength,
            nil,
            dataBytes,
            dataLength,
            bufferPointer,
            bufferLength,
            &numBytesEncrypted)
```

This was working great under Beta 3 and not sure what has changed, even after reading the Beta 4 change log.

Not sure what the issue is, should I open a bug with Apple?

Comment: You mean Swift 1.2, right?

Comment: Sorry, yes -- I'll fix that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Xcode 6.3 beta 4 release notes:

> The C size_t family of types are now imported into Swift as Int, since
>   Swift prefers sizes and counts to be represented as signed numbers,
>   even if they are non-negative. This decreases the amount of explicit
>   type conversion between Int and UInt, better aligns with sizeof
>   returning Int, and provides safer arithmetic properties. (18949559)

Therefore you have to replace

```
let dataLength    = UInt(self.length)
// ...
var numBytesEncrypted: UInt = 0
```

by

```
let dataLength    = self.length // no conversion needed anymore
// ...
var numBytesEncrypted: Int = 0 // or size_t
```

Comment: Doh, missed that bit.   Everything is back to normal.  Cheers!

Comment: Saved me couple of hours of struggle. Much appreciated.